# How to get started with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, jgrasp

I have downloaded the latest version of JFreeChart (1.0.14) and want to start using it. I only have imported standard Java packages like `java.io.*` before and never dealt with 3rd party libraries. What do I need to tell jGRASP so it knows about and can access the JFreeChart library? I have tried to import it like this `import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;` but getting the following error `java:1: package org.jfree.chart does not exist`.

Comment: Did you add JFreeChart jar to the classpath (or buildpath of jGRASP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a library's jar file into both compile-time and run-time [CLASSPATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). In jGRASP you can do it through "Settings > PATH/CLASSPATH > Workspace" dialog. See [HOWTO](http://www.jgrasp.org/jgrasp/howto1.htm), [Control Panel](http://www.jgrasp.org/jgrasp/control.htm#ctrl_top) and [Settings](http://www.jgrasp.org/jgrasp/settings.htm#set_csdwin) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - I added all the jar files in the JFreeChart folder. And now I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

By adding both jar libraries:

```
\jfreechart-1.0.14\lib\jfreechart-1.0.14.jar and
\jfreechart-1.0.14\lib\jcommon-1.0.17.jar
```

into  CLASSPATH, you will be able to use the library straight forward.